# Certain shortcuts dont work in Launchy (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, launchy

I'm using [Launchy](http://www.launchy.net/) with Windows 7, but I've noticed that certain short cut's don't work with Launchy - the icon appears as the generic application icon and the application fails to start.

Clicking on the short cut directly (either on the start menu or in explorer) works fine.

This only happens on a couple of shortcuts - ones that I've noticed so far are Windbg and VirtualBox.

Any idea on what might be causing this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to launchy being an x86 application. Because of that, when it tries to execute a program from the "Program Files" folder, the path is transformed into "Program Files (x86)" and then it fails because the program is not there.

See this post for more information:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/launchy/forums/forum/766268/topic/3356037

Apart from using the x64 beta version, you can use a workaround: create a wsh script that runs your program, and make the shortcut link to that file.

Answer (score 0):

The last release for Launchy seems to date from [8/2008](http://sourceforge.net/projects/launchy/files/).
The [website](http://www.launchy.net/) also says that Launchy was developed to run on XP.

Unless I'm missing the last release, it seems like it's time to find another program launcher, unless somebody takes over the development and bug-fixing (the list of bugs is apparently quite long at the moment).

Comment: I've had no issues with Executor.dk, and it's still in ~activish development.

Comment: Interestingly the programs that can't be opened by launchy also cannot be launched by Executor. I have the programs installed on D drive but it attempts to locate them on C drives.

Comment: You can always create a symbolic link on the C drive to the directory on the D drive, as an ugly workaround.